# Disable rows in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, prism, datatrigger

I have an observablecollection bound to a datagrid. This collection is populated from a search result. I can also add items to the datagrid. I want to disable rows, that were part of the original collection. The new rows added by me, should be editable. My limitation is that, I cannot have a boolean property in the collection to use in a datatrigger. Is there a way to do it?

Edit: Forgot to mention that I am using a MVVM framework.

Comment: `My limitation is that, I cannot have a boolean property in the collection to use in a datatrigger.` means, that you cannot modify the underlying `ViewModel`, which represents an item in the collection?

Comment: @DHN, I meant that I cannot add a boolean property like 'IsEnabled' in my collection item to use in a datatrigger.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot add "IsEnabled" property to items in your collection you can always create new class which inherits from class/type of those items.

```
    public class MyDataGridPresenterClass : OriginalItemClass
    {
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    }
```

And use this new `type` in that `ObservableCollection` Nothing can stop you from doing this... And of course every `MyDataGridPresenterClass` is also `OriginalItemClass` since it inherits from it.

So you can have

```
    ObservableCollection<MyDataGridPresenterClass> DataGridItems
    {
        get { return this.dataGridItems; }
        set
        {
            this.dataGridItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DataGridItems");
        }
    }
```

Now You have `IsEnabled` property so you can use it in that DataTrigger you mentioned, you didn't modify `OriginalItemClass` and everybody is happy. :) And one more thing. Just to be clear :) MVVM is not a framework... MVVM is design pattern. I hope this helps :) Best regards and good luck :)